# Could not get unknown property 'PrivateData' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

There is an open source project [here](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-android).

After trying multiple times to build it, there is an error that make build **Failed :**

> Task failed with an exception.
>
> Where:
>
> Build file '/src/apps/build.gradle' line: 19
>
> What went wrong:
>
> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'apps'.
>
> Could not get unknown property 'PrivateData' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.

Here is **line 19 :**

```
buildscript {
    PrivateData.merge(project, "all-apps")
    ...
}
```

And the defined `PrivateData.merge(...)` is in `/buildSrc/src/main/java/MergePrivateData.kt` file:

```
object PrivateData {

    ...
    @JvmStatic
    @JvmOverloads
    fun merge(project: Project, dataDirName: String = "") {
    ...
    }
...
}
```

The source successful build is [here](https://app.bitrise.io/build/3808f65cbb1cfeb8#?tab=log) and I follow the steps, but I can not find my mistake.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. From the `apps` folder remove the `buildSrc` file.
2. From the root copy the `buildSrc` folder into the `apps` folder and rebuild it.

Comment: I accepted your answer, but the main answer is here :
https://github.com/instructure/canvas-android/pull/1085#issuecomment-724096537

Comment: I followed this answer but did not help. @MHSFisher

Comment: Execution failed for task ':student:transformClassesWithProjectTransformForDevDebug'.
> javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] no such class: insets